# choose file Window automatically OnLoad

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

in upload images script is it possible to show "choose file" Window automatically when open the webpage?

my input button code is:

```
<input type="file" size="45" name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile" class="file margin_5_0"onchange="ajaxUpload(this.form);"/>
```

Thank you.